# Angular ui-select Bind to one property, but show to user another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

This is my html code:

```
      <ui-select ng-model="eVisitorGuest.ArrivalOrganization" theme="" name="arrivalOrganization" options="{selectedDisplayProperty:Name}">
                                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Organizacija dolaska">{{$select.selected.CodeMI}}</ui-select-match>
                                                {{$select.selected.Name}}
                                                <ui-select-choices repeat="evisitorArrivalOrganization in evisitorArrivalOrganizations | propsFilter: {Name: $select.search}">
                                                    <div ng-bind-html="evisitorArrivalOrganization.Name  | highlight: $select.Name"></div>

                                                </ui-select-choices>
                                            </ui-select>
```

I'm saving to database CodeMI Property on arrivalOrganisation object, and everything is fine, angular ui-select binds nicely and selects element in dropdown whose CodeMI property is saved to database. Problem is that I don't want CodeMi property to user but another Name property. How to achive that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following structure in your controller:

```
 $scope.items = [{ name: 'one',
                   value: 1 },
                 { name: 'two',
                   value: 2 },
                 { name: 'three',
                   value: 3 },
                 { name: 'four',
                   value: 4 }];
```

And you want to show just name property of items. You could do the following:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selected" theme="bootstrap" title="Choose Name...">
  <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item.value as item in items track by $index | filter: $select.search">
    <div ng-bind-html="item.name"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Now, dropdown will show name, but when you select one, your $scope.selected will have value of selected item.

I know i'm a "bit" late with the answer, but i hope someone will find it useful. :)